# Redirecting domain with index.php to a clean domain

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect my domain: `http://www.domain.com/index.php` to `http://www.domain.com`. How do I accomplish this task through htaccess?

I am new in htaccess so I'm asking for your help. Thanks.

Comment: this question has been answered thousands of times. search a little:)

Comment: `http://www.domain.com/index.php to http://www.domain.com` => But both are same domains in your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$      / [NC,R,L]
```